Computing a sorting matrix for an upper triangular matrix
Assume I have a real upper triangular matrix $U$, there exists an orthogonal matrix $M$ such that $U' = M^T  U  M$ is also upper triangular and has the same eigenvalues as $U$ but sorted by value.
Is there a fast way of computing $M$?

The Schur decomposition does what you want and can produce the eigenvalues in any order you wish but I don't know if any existing software for computing Schur forms allows you to select the order or defaults to the order you want.

An upper triangular matrix is already in schur form, this is an adjacent problem.

The Schur form can have the eigenvalues in any order. See Theorem 7.1.3 of Golub and Van Loan.

Your problem is called reordering a Schur form. Given the Schur form $U = I \cdot U \cdot I^T$, you want to compute another Schur factorization of the same matrix $U = M \cdot U' \cdot M^T$ with the eigenvalues in a different order on the diagonal.
There is standard Lapack code in numerical libraries for a related task: reordering a Schur form so that a prescribed set of eigenvalues comes first (for instance: those in the unit disk, or those in the left half-plane), because that is a more common goal in applications. Look into ordschur; Matlab's and Julia's ordschur, Scipy's schur's sort= argument.
In your case, however, you do not simply want to partition the eigenvalues into two distinct clusters, but to prescribe a complete ordering. For this complete reordering, you can either use the existing ordschur function as the "divide" step of a quicksort-like algorithm, or reuse Lapack's reordering primitives and write your own low-level code.
I'm afraid that the worst-case cost is still going to be cubic though, unless your starting triangular matrix is already almost sorted: swapping two nearby eigenvalues costs $O(n)$, and moving a single eigenvalue from the last to the first position costs $O(n^2)$.
